# Turning linqExpression in to dictonary key value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following expression:

```
var products = loadOrdr.Payload.LoadOrderVehicles.SelectMany(l => l.LoadOrderComps)
.Select(t => t.Transfer)
.GroupBy(p => p.Product.Name)
.Select(s => s.Sum(p => p.DelVolumeData.VL)).toList();
```

I have a list that has info like this:

```
---Product--- ---Value---

   M1              10

   M1              10

   M1              10

   M2              10

   M2              10
```

The list can vary and contain more tan two items and I want to group it so that it looks like:

```
---Product--- ---SumValue---

   M1              30

   M2              20
```

object structure:

```
public class LoadOrderVehicle : DomainBase
{
    public long LoadOrderId { get; set; }

    [DBIgnore]
    public List<LoadOrderComp> LoadOrderComps { get; set; }
}

   public class LoadOrderComp : DomainBase
    {
        public long LoadOrderVehicleId { get; set; }

        [DBIgnore]
        public Transfer Transfer { get; set; }

       [DBIgnore]
       public VehicleComp VehicleComp { get; set; }
   }

// data I want to group is here:
    public class Transfer : DomainBase
    {
        [DBIgnore]
        public VolumeData OrdVolumeData { get; set; }

        [DBIgnore]
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

Linq is not my strong side and my own linq did not yeild any desiered results. 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies but none of the above gave me the desiered result. With the help from a friend I solved this. I appologize for the late reply, I had other stuff to do before deploy.

This worked:

```
        var transfers = loadOrdr.Payload.LoadOrderVehicles
            .SelectMany(lov => lov.LoadOrderComps)
            .Select(loc => loc.Transfer);

        var products = transfers
            .GroupBy(t => t.Product.Name)
            .ToDictionary(
                g => g.Key,
                g => transfers
                .Where(x => x.Product.Name.Equals(g.Key))
                .Sum(y => y.DelVolumeData.VL));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
var products = loadOrdr.Payload
                       .LoadOrderVehicles
                       .SelectMany(l => l.LoadOrderComps)
                       .Select(t => t.Transfer)
                       .GroupBy(p => p.Product.Name)
                       .Select(gr => new 
                        {
                            ProductName = gr.Key,
                            Total = gr.Sum(p => p.DelVolumeData.VL)
                        })
                       .ToDictinary(x=>x.ProductName, x=>x.Total);
```

The only issue you had was the last projection, `Select` after the `GroupBy`. There you need the key on which you made the grouping and the total sum of `DelVolumeData.VL` of corresponding group items.

Answer (score 2):

**You just need:**

```
.GroupBy(p => p.Product.Name,(pk,s) => 
                                   new {
                                        Key = pk,
                                        Sum = s.Sum(p => p.DelVolumeData.VL)
                                       })
```

This will result into `IEnumerable<Anonymous{string,int}>`, assuming `Name` as `string` and `p.DelVolumeData.VL` as int

Now you can call `ToDictionary` is required and get `Dictionary<string,int>`

**Modified code:**

```
var products = loadOrdr.Payload.LoadOrderVehicles
                      .SelectMany(l => l.LoadOrderComps)
                      .Select(t => t.Transfer)
                      .GroupBy(p => p.Product.Name,
                              (pk,s) => 
                               new {
                                    Key = pk,
                                    Sum = s.Sum(p => p.DelVolumeData.VL)
                                   })
                      .ToDictionary(p => p.Key,p => p.Sum);
```

Comment: The `GroupBy` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) you use does not allow aggregates. You need [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you again, does this looks like a working version. I genuinely need to start testing locally instead of assuming that, I know all the overloads.

Comment: You are welcome. One reason people don't use overloads is that the code looks more unreadable. I'm considering them to be a LINQ to Objects optimizations, in LINQ to Entities it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @IvanStoev agreed, using a concatenated Select makes the overall Linq query far more readable